# How to correct the CoffeeScript cake file

Tags: coffeescript

The following CoffeeScript cakefile doesn't show any output:

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'
task 'watch', 'watch current directory and corrects the map file', (cb)->
    console.log 'hello world'
    exec 'coffee -w -b -m -c .' ,(err,stdout,stderr) ->
        console.log err
        console.log stdout
        throw err if err
        console.log stdout + stderr
```

It is compiling all the files but when I make error in the coffee file, it doesn't throw an error nor does it show anything about the compile files. But the exec command, when tried separately, does show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try spawn instead of exec.  My guess is exec is expecting a buffer but coffee is giving a stream.